# Remove price update for Magento Quantities

Tags: magento-1.9, price, quantity

A client wants to prevent the price from updating when you add more than one in the QTY box, so it always shows the base price until you add it to cart.

```
Is this something that is possible? I've searched and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.
```